# Need to find a way for data entry to start in a specific column after a specific row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my script:

```
function CopyRange() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1EA2F99W1lpgTzX3zoTNpzuEXWh-mDkvo9UyZC4kDNtQ'); //replace with source ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('UKG-A'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
 var range = ss.getRange('G4:K4'); //assign the range you want to copy
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1EA2F99W1lpgTzX3zoTNpzuEXWh-mDkvo9UyZC4kDNtQ'); //replace with destination ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('UKG-A'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name

 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,15,1,5).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()
 

}
```

i have some data in column A to M in between rows 1 to 33. I want to start the data entry to start in column O after 6th row without an effect to the data in column A to M. Is there something like that i can find the last row of column O starting from 6th row and +1 like the original script i have.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col||sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  const rcA=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().reverse()
  let s=0;
  for(let i=0;i<rcA.length;i++) {
    if(rcA[i][0].toString().length==0) {
      s++;
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length-s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

The idea is to find the [index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) of the first non-empty value in column O, starting from the bottom of the sheet up to the 6th row.

**Replace:**

```
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,15,1,5).setValues(data);
```

**with:**

```
const start_row = 6;
const col15 = ts.getRange(start_row,15,ts.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
const index = col15.reverse().findIndex(c=>c!='');
const size = index>-1 ? ts.getLastRow() - index + start_row : start_row;
ts.getRange(size,15,1,5).setValues(data);
```

**References:**

- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)